# Пытаюсь вевести значения в шаблоне из переданного словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dict

Моя задача:

> Прорендерить перенданный словарь в html, выведя тем самым менюшку (заголовки которой и хранятся в словаре)

Мой код (части):
views.py:

```
d = {}
for l1 in lavel.objects.all().filter(lvl=2):
    d[l1.id] = dict()
    d[l1.id]['id'] = l1.id
    d[l1.id]['alias'] = l1.alias
    d[l1.id]['title'] = l1.title
...
context = {
    ...
    'd': d,
}
return render(request, "blog/index.html", context=context)
```

index.html:

```
{% for k in d %}
<li class="menu-category">
    <span>{{ k }}: {{ d.k.title }} <a href="edit.html">edit</a> <i class="icon icon-plus"></i></span>
.........
```

Логический смысл: Вывести меню из словаря

Техническая проблема: Фактически вывелось только 'k' (это временный вывод, показывает просто id записи из БД)
'd.k.title' - как будто его и нет

Физически он существует (проверялся во вьюехе выводом в консоль)
Если обрачаться так: d[k]['title'], то django на меня ругается, и мне становится грустно(

В общем, помогите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Сроки проекта горят уже (курсач скоро сдавать), а я уже 5е сутки сижу с меню... Не одно так другое

Comment: `{{ k.id }}: {{ k.title }}` а так ?

Comment: К сожалению, ничего не изменилось..(

Comment: а вообще зачем вам такая запись  в словарь ? Почему  не хватает просто  `lavel.objects.filter(lvl=2)` ?

Comment: Это не весь код, в словарь я вкладываю все пункты верхнего уровня, в каждый из которых вношу еще словарь, содержащий 2й уровень, и далее 3й, + к каждому элементу, кроме title, приписывается еще некоторое количество мета-ифнормации... В общем, как-то так) Если у вас есть мысли, как можно было это сделать оптимальнее, я был бы благодарен, если поделиесь =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не знаю зачем вам такой словарь. Но перебор по словарю ничем не отличается от того как это делается в `python`.

```
{% for k,v in d.items %}
     {{k}}:{{v.title}} 
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Это, блин, работает!)

Comment: Что вы имели ввиду, когда удивлялись цели словаря? Меню у меня трехуровневое, и чтобы прорендерить его, я не нашел другого решения, кроме пройтись по словарю в тройном форе... У вас есть другие варианты?

Comment: @MaksZubko ну у вас 2 и 3 уровень идут по ForeignKey или как-то по-другому?

Comment: @MaksZubko ну если вам помог ответ, вы можете проголосовать за него или отметить как решение)

Comment: 2 и 3 уровень - одна и та же таблица (реализация списков смежностей), ибо сущности идентичны. У каждого элемента, есть owner, ссылающийся на id этой же таблицы, но другой сущности (вроде не напутал)
Да, ответ мне ваш помог, отмечу)
Спасибо еще раз))